# Как правильно экспортировать переменные для других приложений при написании NodeJS-библиотек на TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

Поскольку я не хочу иметь кучу выходных JavaScript-файлов в результате компилирования TypeScript-а, я рассматриваю Webpack для написания NodeJS- библиотек на TypeScript. Результатом внедрения такой методики в большинстве случаев станет возможным получать на выходе один-единственный `index.js`. Ещё раз повторюсь: в этом вопросе речь идёт не о браузерных веб-приложениях, а о nodejs-приложениях.

Если просто собрать **Webpack**-ом приведённый ниже **node_modules/some_dependency/index.ts**, класс **Dependency** не будет виден в **index.babel.js**, потому что по умолчанию Webpack не создаёт переменный, доступных извне.

### index.babel.js

```
require('@babel/register');

// node_modules/some_dependency/index.js (откомпилированный TypeScript)
import Dependency form 'dependency'; // Error!

new Dependency();
```

### node_modules/some_dependency/index.ts

```
export default class Dependency() {
   // ---
}
```

В отличие от веб-приложения, у нас NodeJS-модули, и впридачу исходный код на TypeScript. Как правильно обеспечить видимость класса Dependency внутри **index.babel.js**?

Answer (score 0):

Минимальная настройка **webpack.confing.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './TypeScriptSource/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: __dirname,
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  }
};
```

Теперь, если в `TypeScriptSource/index.ts` класс `Dependency` имеет `export default`, приведённый ниже код в `index.babel.js` будет работать без ошибок:

```
require('@babel/register');

import Dependency from 'some-depencency';
new Dependency();
```

Необходимые зависимости для `index.babel.js`:

```
"@babel/core": "7.1.2",
"@babel/node": "7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.1.0",
"@babel/register": "7.0.0",
```

Comment: позвольте поинтересоваться, а зачем вы используете babel в ноде с тайпскриптом?